# I installed package, but python said No moudel <name-packages> any packages I try to install it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, package

I try using pip and pip3 and python -m pip and all ways to install. The terminal says the packages already installed after the first try to install, but when I try to import the package I had error no moudel name.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I feel the peoblem coming form here
[image]

But I am not sure

And when I go to packages in pycharm I saw the packages not installed

[image]

**I appreciate your help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using windows.

It looks like you install the package directly in your system and PyCharm are using a virtual environment to run your code.

Try to activate this virtual environment  before run your code:

```
source venv\Scripts\activate
```

If you see "(venv)" at the begging of your terminal prompt the virtual environment are activated.

Run `pip list` to check what packages are installed in there and probably you have to install your package another time, this time in your activated virtual environment. [The official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#:%7E:text=A%20virtual%20environment%20is%20a,part%20of%20your%20operating%20system.) will help to understand how and why use virtual environments.

After that you can try to run your code directly from the terminal:

```
python your_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the packages from PyCharm itself, not the terminal as I think pycharm is running a virtual environment.

Maybe you can follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#packages-tool-window